Django IntegrityError: How to handle ForeignKeyViolation in a delete view?
I’m facing an issue when trying to delete records in Django. I have a delete function for companies, but sometimes I encounter an IntegrityError if the company has related records in another table. I tried handling the IntegrityError, but it doesn’t help—the error occurs after the try-except block and results in a 500 error. Here’s my code:
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('autintification'))
def delete_cp_company(request):
    db_name = LOCAL_DB if DEBUG else request.get_host().split(".")[0]
    cp_company_ids = json.loads(request.POST.get('cp_company_ids'))
    no_del = []
    for ids in cp_company_ids:
        company = CP_company_for_pattern.objects.using(db_name).get(id=ids)
        print('id', ids)
        try:
            company.delete()
        except:
            no_del.append({
                'id': company.id,
                'name': company.com_name,
            })
    return JsonResponse(data={'no_delete': no_del})

Here’s the JavaScript that sends the delete request:
function delete_cp_company() {
    let check_box = $('.cp_company_list_block .check_for_choose_item');
    let ids_to_delete = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < check_box.length; i++) {
        if (check_box[i].checked) {
            let deleted_tr = $(check_box[i]).closest('tr');
            let deleted_tr_id = deleted_tr.data("id");

            ids_to_delete.push(deleted_tr_id);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/delete_cp_company",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            cp_company_ids: JSON.stringify(ids_to_delete),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            processCompanyDelete(ids_to_delete, data.no_delete)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + ' - ' + error);
        },
    });
}

I tried handling the IntegrityError in the try-except block, but the error still causes a 500 response. I also tried adding more specific error handling and using Django transactions, but nothing seems to work. The main issue is that the exception is raised after the try-except block when Django attempts to commit the transaction.
Here’s the error I receive:
id 11
id 4
Internal Server Error: /delete_cp_company
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 253, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: update or delete on table "CRM_App_cp_company_for_pattern" violates foreign key constraint "CRM_App_contract_tab_our_company_id_370011ff_fk_CRM_App_c" on table "CRM_App_contract_table"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) is still referenced from table "CRM_App_contract_table".

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/path/to/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/path/to/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 253, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "CRM_App_cp_company_for_pattern" violates foreign key constraint "CRM_App_contract_tab_our_company_id_370011ff_fk_CRM_App_c" on table "CRM_App_contract_table"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) is still referenced from table "CRM_App_contract_table".

HTTP POST /delete_cp_company 500 [0.11, 127.0.0.1:58081]

How can I properly handle this error to prevent it from causing a 500 error?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error says that there's an object with a foreign key to this company and if you'd delete the company this foreign key would be null which is not allowed.
Most likely in your models.py you have a foreign key with null=False and on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING.
class CRM_App_contract_table(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

So you either have to change this to null=True or models.CASCADE
